# Read GCS blob where file name is coming from previous p-collection in apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, parquet

I am trying to read a **GCS parquet blob** where the file name is coming from the **previous p-collection** in the apache beam. The code sample is below.

```
pubsub = (p | "Read from Topic" >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic) 
            |"decode bytes" >>beam.Map(lambda element: element.decode('utf-8')) # b'"gs://beam-gcs/example.parquet"'
            | "Read from Parquet" >> **beam.io.?????** #"gs://beam-basics-gcs/example.parquet"
         )
ib.show(pubsub)
```

I want to use a streaming dataflow job where I am expecting different filename through **pubsub topics**. And finally, after **reading** the parquet I want to ingest into **bigquery**

Answer (score 1):

To read the contents of a PCollection of filenames, you can use [ReadAllFromParquet](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html#apache_beam.io.parquetio.ReadAllFromParquet).

Comment: `pubsub = (p | "Read from Topic" >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic)
 
|"decode bytes" >>beam.Map(lambda element: element.decode('utf-8'))  #b'"gs://beam-gcs/example.parquet"'

| beam.io.parquetio.ReadAllFromParquet(min_bundle_size=0, desired_bundle_size=67108864,columns="shopid", label='ReadAllFiles')
         )`


The above I tried and passing different combinations inside ReadAllFromParquet.  what I am doing wrong @robertwb

Comment: my column selection was wrong.. it should be like: columns=['shopid','shopdate']

Comment: Is it working with the correct column suggestion?

Comment: beam.io.parquetio.ReadAllFromParquet(columns=['id','date']) 

That works. thanks @robertwb

Answer (score 0):

Error depicts *beam.io.ReadFromParquet()* expects a file pattern that points to set of Parquet files , but none is provided .

A PCollection for the records in Parquet files can be created in the following manner.

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
records = p | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet('/mypath/mypqfiles*')

where /mypath/myparquetfiles* is a file-pattern that points to a set of Parquet files.

Please include Praquet file path,from where you want to read and try to rerun dataflow job.

Reference:
https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html#apache_beam.io.parquetio.ReadFromParquet

Comment: How to pass the file name which is coming from the previous p-collection?? @priyank